# My Laplace Transform vs. My Desmos laplace Transform

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

If I were to calculate the Laplace Transform of 1 I would do the following:
\begin{equation}\mathcal{L}\{1\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}dt \end{equation}
From here I would go on evaluate the improper integral:\begin{align}&=-\frac{1}s[e^{-st}]\Bigg\vert_0^\infty \\&=\frac{1}s[e^{-s\cdot0}-e^{-\infty \cdot s}]\end{align}
So the end result would be that I would get $\mathcal{L}\{1\}=\frac{1}s$.
I plotted this on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w1amxfjoqe). I used a really big upper limit for the approximation and saw it matches the positive x axis part of only of $\frac{1}x$. Why is that? Does this have heavy implications differential equations and/or calculus if so please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evaluation of this improper integral is valid only for $s>0$.  For $s \le 0$ the integral diverges to $\infty$.  By replacing $\infty$ by some large number $R$, the integral becomes
$$ \frac{1}{s} \left(1 - e^{-Rs}\right)$$
When $s< 0$ the $e^{-Rs}$ is a very large number.